# Regular Expression Pattern C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following string that would require me to parse it via Regex in C#.

> Format: rec_mnd.rate.current_rate.sum.**QWD.RET : 214345**

I would like to extract our the bold chars as group objects in a groupcollection.

QWD = 1 group
RET = 1 group
214345 = 1 group

what would the message pattern be like?

Comment: What pattern have you got so far?

Comment: Just as a reference, I've found this site useful. When you get something that matches it gives you the C# regex http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
string s = "Format: rec_mnd.rate.current_rate.sum.QWD.RET : 214345";
Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"^Format: rec_mnd\.rate\.current_rate\.sum\.(.+?)\.(.+?) : (\d+)$");
if( m.Success )
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[3].Value);
}
```

The question mark in the first two groups make that quantifier lazy: it will capture the least possible amount of characters. In other words, it captures until the first `.` it sees. Alternatively, you could use `([^.]+)`  in those groups, which explicitly captures everything except a period.

The last group explicitly only captures decimal digits. If your expression can have other values on the right side of the `:` you'd have to change that to `.+` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Please, make it a lot easier on yourself and label your groups to make it easier to understand what is going on in code.

```
RegEx myRegex = new Regex(@"rec_mnd\.rate\.current_rate\.sum\.(?<code>[A-Z]{3})\.(?<subCode>[A-Z]{3})\s*:\s*(?<number>\d+)");

var matches = myRegex.Matches(sourceString);
foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    //do stuff
    Console.WriteLine("Match");
    Console.WriteLine("Code:    " + match.Groups["code"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("SubCode: " + match.Groups["subCode"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Number:  " + match.Groups["number"].Value);
}
```

Comment: I normally do that, but I couldn't think of good names for the groups from his description. :)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you want regardless of what's between the .'s.

```
@"(?:.+\.){4}(.\w+)\.(\w+)\s?:\s?(\d+)"
```